# Wrong numerical data in the legend of a Seaborn scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, scatter-plot, numeric, categorical

I wish to plot the following data with a seaborn scatterplot with the correct dates.

```
import pandas as pd   
import seaborn as sns

data = [['Sample_1', 130, 325, 1989], ['Sample_2', 128, 348, 1999], ['Sample_3', 150, 258, 2018], ['Sample_4', 171, 534, 2018], ['Sample_5', 171, 536, 2018], ['Sample_6', 278, 899, 2018], ['Sample_7', 726, 1809, 2020]]    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'NROH',  'SROH', 'date'])

sns.scatterplot(x='SROH', y='NROH', hue='date', data=df)
```

On the plot, the legend show:

- 1980
- 1995
- 2020
- 2025

The results I want are the correct inputs:

- 1989
- 1999
- 2018
- 2020

Comment: Perhaps you should check the error message, cause I use your code and it plots nothing wrong. How about you try it in Colab.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Baron Legendre. My question was confusing, I edit it to show the problem better.

Comment: Yes, I just copy your code and run it, I didn't change anything, the legend of my plot is `1989`, `1999`, `2018`, `2020`, how about you explicitly specify the `hue=df['date']`

Comment: Thank you @BaronLegendre, I have tried with `hue=df['date']`, and still don't get the right label for the legend, contrary to you. 

I use Python3 on JupyterLab. Could it be the cause of the difference?

Comment: I use python 3.9.x, Anaconda's JupyterLab. I'm wondering is there any other `df` that infects your `df['date']`, you know, sometimes a little mistake happened, how about you start a new book for the test?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @BaronLegendre, it is an error that I make all the time indeed. In this case the error came from an outdated version of the softwares. I have updated to Python 3.10.5, Pandas 1.4.3, and Seaborn 0.11.2, and the script is working as you described. Thank you!